# How to send specific NFT ids when calling Scrypto component with resim

Tags: smartcontracts, scrypto

I have the following resources in my account:
[image]

I am able to create a bucket containing my three NFTs with the `3,036e1...e0144` syntax but how can I send only the NFT with id 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to create a bucket containing specific NFTs:

```
"#4,[resource_address]" // To send NFT with id #4
"#3,#5,[resource_address]" // to send NFTs with id #3 and #5
```

Don't forget the quotation marks !

Comment: is `resim transfer` used to transfer nft's? can you show me the full command. I am getting NonFungibleLocalId(#0#) as my id.